CVE-2024-47535: io.netty/netty-common
I have a spring-boot application, which contains the following dependency
      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-webflux-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

when i run the code through docker-desktop in it's vulnerability section i get the following Vulnerability
CVE-2024-47535
after some investigation i found out that the above dependency is the cause of the warning, so to resolve it i added the following dependency
 <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-codec-http</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.115.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-codec-http2</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.115.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-resolver-dns</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.115.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-codec-dns</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.115.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-handler</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.115.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-common</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.115.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-buffer</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.115.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-codec</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.115.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-transport</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.115.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-resolver</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.115.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-resolver-dns-native-macos</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.115.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-resolver-dns-classes-macos</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.115.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-transport-native-unix-common</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.115.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-transport-native-epoll</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.115.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-transport-classes-epoll</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.115.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-handler-proxy</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.115.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-codec-socks</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.115.Final</version>
        </dependency>

when i run the Vulnerability scan again, i still get the same WARNING, any help how to resolve it?
